# Reseting the player position when a certain Y coordinate is reached

Tags: character, coordinates, physics, reset

My problem is that whenever my character reaches a certain Y coordinate, I want his position to reset at (destination x, destination y). This is what I have so far, and it isn't working. All of the other code works, but whenever I walk to the certain Y coordinate, it doesn't do anything. I named the boolean for the certain Y coordinate "death".

```
    boolean death = false;

    if (jumper.getPosition().y == 1.0f ) {
        death = true;
    }
```

And here is where I try to reset it:

```
    if (death == true) {
        create();
    }
```

Comment: You must be kidding. Come up with a minimal example, take this to codereview, or both.

Comment: That's better. In general, it's not a good idea to use `==` with floating point numbers, since it's hard to hit them exactly. Try `y >= 1.0f`, or `abs(y-1.0f) < 0.0001` or something, depending on your intention.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just simplify it to this:

```
if (jumper.getPosition().y == 1.0f ) {
    // Print something here
    create();
}
```

And if it's not working it might be because the conditional isn't correct ... so you most likely want to make sure the type is the same so you can compare properly and that you are accessing the object you actually want to access. (You might want to make both ints if you're doing 1 because well floats are funsies and some values aren't well represented so if you're doing a bunch of computation on it you can easily throw values off).

Comment: This works for me, but I changed "==" to "<". After I reach the Y coordinate though, it takes a second for it to load back up. Anyway to  speed up this process?

Comment: Depends, you most likely will need to look into the getPosition() function and create() function as those are most likely where the slow down is occurring.